# Why do I get a warning when return a pointer to a string?

Tags: c, string

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *returnStr(char lst[][6], int index) {
    return &lst[index];
}

int main() {
    char ls[5][6];
    strcpy(ls[0], "pages");
    strcpy(ls[1], "bluff");
    strcpy(ls[2], "test");
    strcpy(ls[3], "yawn");
    strcpy(ls[4], "arch");

    printf("%s\n", returnStr(ls, 2));
}
```

I do not see anything wrong with it, it compiles and does seem to work as intended, but I still get this warning when compiling:

```
main.c: In function ‘returnStr’:
main.c:5:12: warning: returning ‘char (*)[6]’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘char *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    5 |     return &lst[index];
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is the type wrong? What am I supposed to be using as a return type instead?

Comment: Use `return lst[index]`.

Comment: Summarising @Barmar: think types. (and values ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return type is `char*` and the return value is `lst[index]` (without the `&`).

the full working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* returnStr(char lst[][6], int index) {
    return lst[index];
}

int main() {
    char ls[5][6];
    strcpy(ls[0], "pages");
    strcpy(ls[1], "bluff");
    strcpy(ls[2], "test");
    strcpy(ls[3], "yawn");
    strcpy(ls[4], "arch");

    printf("%s", returnStr(ls, 2));
}
```

Comment: The return type cannot be `char [6]`. The return type of a function may not be an array. It could be `char (*)[6]`, but that is not what OP wants.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the return type of A function may not be an array, but the return type of THE GIVEN function is always an array as the input type is char[][6] and he returns only one position of the first array.

Comment: No, the return type of the given function an array. A pointer to a `char` is not an array, and a pointer to a `char [6]` is not an array. The function is declared to return `char *`, which is not an array, and the return statement attempted to return a `char (*)[6]`, which is not an array.

Comment: read again the code. read again my answer. read again what you wrote. `char*` is a pointer and could be pointed to the first position of an array. `char[6]` is an array of char.

Comment: I have read the code, your answer, and what I wrote. What I wrote was correct when I wrote it; you have edited the answer since.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Isn't this a case where the array type will decay to a pointer?

Comment: @Barmar: Arrays in function return types do not “decay”; they are not subject to automatic conversion or adjustment. You simply cannot have a return type that is an array, because C 2018 6.7.6.3 1 says “A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array type.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wasn't talking about the return type, I was talking about the array in `return lst[index];`. It decays to `return &lst[index][0];`, which matches the return type of the function.

Comment: @Barmar: My comments were about the answer as it was at the time I commented. It said “return type could be either `char[6]` or `char*`.” It cannot.

Comment: Oops, I looked at the edit history, but didn't notice that change in the text. @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 0):

You're returning, basically, a `char**`. Simply remove the `&`:

```c
    return lst[index];
```

Comment: A `char (*)[6]` is not a `char **`. Not basically, not technically, not in any way.

Comment: I answer to someone who don't understand what `char (*)[6]` is and why it isn't compatible with a `char*`. He returned the address of a `char*` instead of the `char*` itself... So kind of a `char**`. Be my guest, make your own answer, if mine don't please you.